# How to Get the driver type of DSN?

Tags: c#, odbc, dsn

I have got the list of DSN in my machine alike

```
    private IEnumerable<string> EnumDsn(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rootKey)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey =  rootKey.OpenSubKey(@"Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources");
    if (regKey != null)
    {
        foreach (string name in regKey.GetValueNames())
        {
            string value = regKey.GetValue(name, "").ToString();
            yield return name;
        }
    }
}
```

My intention is to get the driver type of each DSN , how to get to it .

Answer (score 0):

You can call [SQLGetPrivateProfileString Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from odbccp32.dll to retrieve the information that you're looking for.

Use `"ODBC Data Sources"` as the argument to lpszSection and your data source name (DSN) as the argument to lpszEntry. The value returned in the buffer will be your driver name.

Importing the DLL and function looks like this in C#:

```
    [DllImport("odbccp32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int SQLGetPrivateProfileStringW(string lpszSection, string lpszEntry, string lpszDefault, char[] RetBuffer, int cbRetBuffer, string lpszFilename);
```

It looks like this in VB.NET:

```
    <DllImport("odbccp32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
    Private Shared Function SQLGetPrivateProfileStringW(lpszSection As String, lpszEntry As String, RetBuffer As Char(), cbRetBuffer As Integer, lpszFilename As String) As Integer
```